# Different size of the components in the view depending of the operating system or target

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

I am working in a hybrid application which target is Windows 8.1 and iOS, but I am looking the size of the components (buttons for example) are different.

I would like to know how to handle this difference in terms of size depending of the application target?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do... but I think issues you are having is that UI elements are styled differently in different browsers.

This is a common problem we all face... not to worry, just use [reset.css](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) so that all your ui elements appear similar across different browsers and operating systems.

--- EDIT : RWD solution for different resolutions ---

If you want to have different style adjustments for different resolutions... you can go for [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)...

If you have just started building the app, a front end framework, like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), will get you up and running quickly.
[Learn more about bootstrap grids here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

But if you have most of stuff done media queries is the way to go.

Comment: Simply same cordova application has differents sizes in ipad or Windows 8.1 tablet

Comment: Okay... can you add some screenshots showing what is happening and what you wanna do...?

Comment: In windows 8.1 we have a screen with different inch and different resolution, it is normal to have changes in the visualization, but I would like to minimize these differences. Thank you for your help but it is not possible to attach screenshots of the app.

Comment: Hi Inane,
You may wanna use media queries to style elements differently at different resolutions... Updated my answer, lemme know if that helps :)

Comment: Thank you @Shramee I know the media queries concept and I will take a look about a possible application for my purpose..